# lazyload-rails shows distorted PNGs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I am using [lazyload-rails](https://github.com/jassa/lazyload-rails) and everything works fine for JPEGs. However, when I have a PNG, the image appears distorted. Please see the image below -

[image]

Would be great if you could help me figure why this is happening.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is how the actual logo looks like -

[image]

Comment: What's distorted about that?

Comment: Just edited the question to include how the original logo looks like.

Comment: That looks like a CSS problem that manifests because of transparency. JPEG does not have that, so perhaps you're not seeing the issue because the smaller version blocks the larger one in the background.